# localhost:27017: [WinError 10061] No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión - Djongo

Tags: django, mongodb, firewall

El día de hoy me encuentro haciendo la conexión de Django con MongoDB Atlas por medio de Djongo

Estos son mis settings:

```
***DATABASES = {
        'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'db name',
        'HOST': 'mongodb+srv://xxx:xxxx@xxxxx-xxxx.mongodb.net/test',
        'USER': '<xxxx>',
        'PASSWORD': '<xxx>',
    }
}**
```

*

Ya habilite el puerto 27017 en mi firewall y en MongoAtlas habilite que cualquier IP pudiera acceder.

Version de Django 2.2.12

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Logre hacer la solución despues de visualizar bien la libreria de Djongo.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'djongo',
            'NAME': 'db name',
            'CLIENT': {
                'host': "mongodb+srv://<username>:" +'<password>'+ "@<cluster-name>-yb6dk.mongodb.net/test"
            },   
        }
```

}